# Combine csv column values in PHP

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv file with 5 rows :

```
id | price|   name  | sku  | qty
1  |  22  | widget0 | abcd | 1
2  |  21  | widget1 | efgh | 1
3  |  10  | widget0 | abcd | 2
4  |  44  | widget1 | efgh | 1
5  |  22  | widget4 | mnop | 1
```

etc...
The first 3 columns are just here for visual purpose and are not used for what I need to achieve.
What I need to do is read the sku and qty data in the file and output the result.
I have to count the number of the same skus and get the total qty per sku.

Based on the example above, I need :

```
sku  | qty
abcd | 3
efgh | 2
ijkl | 1
mnop | 1
```

With the following code, I can get the total number of the same skus in the file :

```
$file = ('my.csv');
$fh = fopen($file, 'rb');
$tag = array();
$qty = array();
$row=1;
while($col = fgetcsv($fh)) {
if($row == 1){ $row++; continue; } //skip 1st row
$num = count($fh);
if (isset($tag[$col[3]])) {
$tag[$col[3]]++;
}
else {
$tag[$col[3]] = 1;
}
}
print_r($tag);
```

It gives me :

```
sku  | qty
abcd | 2
efgh | 2
ijkl | 1
mnop | 1
```

Which is not correct. I don't know how to get the qty column value and associate it to the total number of skus value in the csv file.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code for your solution

```
$file = ('my.csv');
$fh = fopen($file, 'rb');
$tag = array();
$qty = array();
$row=1;
while($col = fgetcsv($fh)) {
if($row == 1){ $row++; continue; } //skip 1st row
$num = count($fh);
if (isset($tag[$col[3]])) {
//$tag[$col[3]]++;
$tag[$col[3]] = (int)$tag[$col[3]] + (int)$col[4]; // where $col[4] = qty with forcing to `int` value
}
else {
$tag[$col[3]] = $col[4];
}
}
print_r($tag);
```

you need to make SUM of quantity instead just increase with +1

Hope this will help!

Comment: WC. please upvote the answer and accept it so it will be use for other user will have same thing. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this solution

```
$file = ('my.csv');
$fh = fopen($file, 'rb');
$tag = array();
$qty = array();
$row=1;

//skip first row
fgetcsv($fh, 10000, ",");

while($col = fgetcsv($fh,10000)) {

$num = count($fh);
if (isset($tag[$col[3]])) {
$tag[$col[3]]++;
}
else {
$tag[$col[3]] = 1;
}
}
print_r($tag);
```